# function pointer to a function which has variable argument list

Tags: c++, pointers, stl, function-pointers

Can we have a function pointer which points to a function which use a varying argument list? 
For example, lets say i need to select a function among a number of functions based on some input T 'input'. Can i use a STL map somthing like this??

```
template<typename T>
map<T, T (*)(T, ...)> func_map;
```

If this is possible can you tell me doing so will be right thing to do with design perspective.

---

[Edit] 
Actually i have a set of algorithmic functions and i have a message field. I need to select this algorithmic function based on few bytes values on this msg. I was thinking to use hash_map with a key value w.r.t. the pointer to that algorithmic function. i wanted to be very fast as per performance, what can be bast way to implement this.

Also, the reason why i am not selecting simple if-else or switch block for this is because the value which tell us the function that need to execute can refer to some other function at later point.

Comment: It just popped in my head. got curious and wi-fi so this question. srry didnt tried it yet :(

Comment: Note that there are no template typedefs, so what you wrote doesn't really exist, but in principle the answer is "yes".

Comment: @Marcelo - Thanks marcelo. didnt know there was a site that can run code so easily. Its a going to be my frequest bookmark.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible to do this, but you probably shouldn't. There are a number of problems with variadic functions, including:

- All types passed must be POD types or the behavior is undefined
- There is no type safety whatsoever. If you pass the wrong type, you will cause undefined behavior.

I would recommend you find another approach. If you give more specifics on why you need to do this, perhaps someone can give you a better option.

Comment: People keep telling me that I should write stuff like this `std::cout << '(' << p.x << ', ' << p.y << ', ' << p.z << '): ' << type << std::endl;` instead of like this `printf("(%g, %g, %g): %s\n", p.x, p.y, p.z, type)`. I get the reasoning, but seriously, this is progress? The `...` construct is hazardous and should be handled with heat-resistant forceps, but sometimes it just hits the spot.

Comment: C++0x might yield a very nice solution via user-defined literals. Something like `"(%g, %g, %g): %s\n"F` (note the `F` suffix) could resolve to a functor that takes four arguments of type double, double, double and const char*. Of course, this doesn't help with defining the OP's `func_map`. Indeed, I struggle to think of a viable alternative.

Comment: @MarceloCantos: Do you know about [Boost Format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/format/doc/format.html)?

Comment: @Daniel: Yes, and it is a distinct improvement over `<<`. but I want something that refuses to compile if my format string is wrong. Interestingly, conventional printf already exhibits this behaviour thank to very smart compilers.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think variable lists of arguments is a bad idea. It prevents you from using the compiler to do type checking and therefore make it easier to find bugs before any object code is produced.

I would therefore recommend that you find a way around this.